# Show and delete Files in a folder from today

Tags: command-line, 22.04, delete, rm

1. How can I use `ll` to display the files in a folder from today, eg. `folder = /home/me/Downloads | today = 21.11.2023`?
2. How can I delete the result from 1. (displayed files) then using `rm`?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest is to create a reference file with today's date `23/11/21` at `00:00` o'clock like so:

```
touch -t 2311210000 /tmp/ref
```

then use it with `find`'s `-newer` like so:

```
find /home/me/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer /tmp/ref -ls
```

... and if the output is what you want, then delete those files with:

```
find /home/me/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -type f -newer /tmp/ref -delete
```

**Notice** `-newer` checks for and compares the last data modification time of a file and **not** creation time.

Answer (score 0):

To view the files created on 11/21 I use
 `ll -ltr | grep "Nov 21"`

To view the files created after 8pm on 11/21 I use
 `ll -ltr | grep "Nov 21 20"`

Comment: That is modification time and not creation time ... Also parsing the output of `ls` is not recommended especially when you want to pass it to `rm` for example or any other tool for that matter ... Please see [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985)